# Removing space before a TD content

Tags: html, css

I created a simple HTML table to position different page contents: texts, buttons...

I want to remove additional space displaying in every `<td>`,  appearing before the content of the `<td>`.

[image]

See picture above. Space before text.

Sorry I was obliged to remove the text content.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: It is probably because of `padding`; but it would really help if you posted some code so we don't have to guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Try applying this style

```
#yourtableid td
{
   padding-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, the padding-top: 0; didn't give me the result i wanted but here's what i found as a solution:

Adding

```
    margin-top: -18%;
```

in the content div style

Comment: If you had posted your code we could have helped. If your fix works, then fine, but it's very strange.